# Tensorflow projection in loss function?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, loss-function, disparity-mapping

I would like to use this function in Tensorflow loss function:

```
def rectified_projection(self, disp_x, image):
    H, W, B = self.HEIGHT, self.WIDTH, self.batch_size
    disp_x = tf.cast(disp_x, tf.int32)
    disp_x = self.bias_x + disp_x
    disp = tf.concat([self.disp_y, disp_x], 3)
    disp = tf.clip_by_value(disp, 0, W)
    sdisp = tf.scatter_nd(disp, image, (B, H, W, 3), name="SCATTER")
    return sdisp
```

This code moves pixels of `image` in row by the value of `disp_x` which is output from layer.

The problem is when I want to traing my network with this transformation. Tensorflow outputs that dont know how to propagate gradients through the network.. How can it be fixed?

**EDIT:**

**Complete Error message:**

```
 ValueError: 
 No gradients provided for any variable, 
 check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, 
 between variables "last_layer" "loss_function"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a common issue  when you use `tf.clip()`

SOLUTION : Use a bijective function from R to [0,W] like : `vector = W * (vector / (2*tf.reduce_max(tf.abs(vector)))+0.5)`, for which a gradient can be calculated...

Comment: Thx for your answer. I know what you mean, but the error accurs even if I remove the clipping. I think, that the `tf.cast` and `tf.scatter` makes the problem